# Are there any good and free tools for managing a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, tools, management

Before, I have used phpmyadmin to manage an MySQL database, but now I would like to manage a PostgreSQL database. The PostgreSQL database is on a server, but not a webserver, so I don't use PHP.

Are there any good and free tools for managing a PostgreSQL database?

I have tried with pgAdmin III but it was a far from intuitive application to use, compared to phpmyadmin that I have used before. What are PostgreSQL DBAs usually using? do they use graphical tools like pgAdmin III or is it mostly command line tools?

Comment: There is a long list in the PostgreSQL Wiki: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: [dbForge Studio for PostgreSQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/postgresql/studio/) is released! The Express edition is absolutely free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [Navicat for PostgreSQL](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_pgsql/pgsql_overview.html) and other database platforms.

It has a free lite and a commercial version.

Comment: I do not think they offer the free lite version

Comment: navicat is great, but I also wished it came with a free version... If you have any link to provide, it would be most welcome.

Comment: I have found Navicat for PostgreSQL to be buggy and unreliable over the years

Answer (score 21):

pgAdmin and psql, those are the tools I use. A PHP-script isn't very usefull for database management, too slow and many problems with transactions: What to do when something goes wrong? Commit or rollback? This makes tools like phpmyadmin and phpPgAdmin pretty useless, when the script is done, the database connection will be closed. There is nothing to commit or rollback, your SQL script is already gone.

Learn SQL and any tool that can keep it's databases connections open, will do the job.

Comment: I have used pgAdmin and `psql` a few months now, but I'm disappointed. The result sets from `psql` looks terrible on Windows, it's almost impossible to read, when having many columns. And it's hard to get a good workflow using pgAdmin, e.g. see [How can I access the query history with SQL Editor in pgAdmin III?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5963/how-can-i-access-the-query-history-with-sql-editor-in-pgadmin-iii)

Answer (score 5):

Coming from Microsoft SQL Server, I really like http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/postgresql/manager/  for managing PostgreSQL.

The free version has most everything you would need to get started.

Answer (score 5):

Check out **[JackDB](http://www.jackdb.com/)**, it's a database client entirely in your web browser.

There's no software to install locally so you can use it on Mac OS X, Linux, and Windows and it works on all major modern browsers (eg. Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, and Opera). It supports connecting to PostgreSQL, as well as MySQL, Oracle, and SQL Server databases.

At the moment (July 13') it's more of a full featured query editor but it also includes GUI-based management features for things like changing runtime config parameters or vacuuming tables.

Regarding your [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/are-there-any-good-and-free-tools-for-managing-a-postgresql-database/6490#comment1596_1284) in another answer above about SQL history (linked to a removed question), JackDB includes a full history of all SQL commands both per connection (searchable locally) and across all connections/datasources (searchable globally).

*Full disclosure*: I'm the founder of JackDB.

Comment: And how do I use this against a local database running on my desktop or on a local server?

Comment: At the moment you can't with the cloud version without opening up remote ports from your local machine. We're looking into couple of ways to simplify that (http://progrium.com/localtunnel/ looks cool though it's http only) but for now it works best with cloud databases that are already network accessible (ex: Heroku Postgres, Amazon RDS, etc).

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is phpPgAdmin, if that suits you.

Comment: That sounds good. But at the moment I don't have a webserver and I'm not running PHP. Is there any similar GUI tools? It would also be helpful if it was possible to log in to a remote database via SSH.

Answer (score 3):

I like dbVisualizer, it has a free version that unfortunately is missing some features, you'll have to see if it has enough for you.

also check out stackoverflow for more choices:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105788/good-postgresql-client-for-windows
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532620/good-front-end-for-postgresql-on-windows-or-mac